# XPath to find elements

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I wouldn't mind a little help with some xpath for selenium. From the below HTML I am trying to grab a list of links, from within the articles, but only for the available items.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="listing">
            <h3>Available</h3>
            <article>
                <a href="article.php?id=123">
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="listing">
            <h3>Sold</h3>
            <article>
                <a href="article.php?id=123">
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I've got...

```
//h3[. = 'Available']/ancestor::div[1]//article//a
```

I would point out that the first div (listing) is only available when there are items available for sale.

Comment: Added two closing quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following XPath

```
//div[h3 = 'Available']/article/a
```

It will return all `a` elements which are in the same `div` as `h3` elements with the value "Available".

The result may seem empty because the `a` elements themselves have no values. But if you try to access the `@href` attributes, you'll get a visible result.